# How to tweak c3po & mysql tandem for performance?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, c3p0, spring-jdbc

Moving forward question is: why com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable() eats that crazy amount of execution time? And - how to fix that?

Now let me give you details...

**Background:**
I have Spring MVC java web application which uses SpringJDBC for data access. Data source configured as follows:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.databaseurl}" />
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="${c3po.testConnectionOnCheckout}" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${c3po.minPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${c3po.maxPoolSize}" />
    <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="${c3po.checkoutTimeout}" />
    <property name="maxStatementsPerConnection" value="${c3po.maxStatementsPerConnection}" />
</bean>
```

Related properties:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/timesheet?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=somepassword
c3po.testConnectionOnCheckout=true
c3po.minPoolSize=5
c3po.maxPoolSize=200
c3po.checkoutTimeout=30000
c3po.maxStatementsPerConnection=50
```

**Current intention:**
Prepare application for public availability. So I created very simple JMeter test plan which uses 500 concurrent threads to simple open index page of the application again and again.

**Problem:**
Is that I see very poor performance appox 140 requests per second with average request time 1700ms, which is completely unacceptable. 
Note that without load test in normal situation such request take approx.. 6ms.
So what I did - I ran jvisualvm, and profiled. 
And it looks like it is com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable() which eats most execution time.
[image: jvisualvm profiler screenshot]

**Question:**
why com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable() eats that crazy amount of execution time? And - how to fix that?

NOTE 1: Of course I'm considering to add more caching logic to avoid calls to database, but here and now I'm more interested in c3po & mysql optimization.

NOTE 2: I'm running Windows 7 x64, which is not production environment (it will be CentOS), but still having top level i7 intel processor and SSD disk I expect more performance =)

Comment: Don't use C3P0 :). I would recommend [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) I have better experience with that. Also your poolside doesn't make sense, too large a pool will kill your performance, [nice read here](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing). Next running tests on different hardware and OS as in production is IMHO a useless exercise as OS can have quite an impact.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I just tried it. Well... Apparently it shows MUCH better performance! BUT application is not answering to requests from the browser now =) Not sure why, first guess - tomcat is dead =)

Comment: Are you sure it isn't answering or is your test maybe flawed? Does the normal application work?

Comment: Yes, firefox shows me empty page. I think it's somehow related to test environment and fact I'm running Jmeter at the same machine where tomcat is running. Jmeter says "connection close", maybe it's related to limits of operation system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you define a `preferredTestQuery`, for instance `SELECT 1`.

From http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#preferredTestQuery

```
preferredTestQuery
Default: null
        Defines the query that will be executed for all connection tests, 
        if the default ConnectionTester (or some other implementation of 
        QueryConnectionTester, or better yet FullQueryConnectionTester) is being used. 
        Defining a preferredTestQuery that will execute quickly in your database may 
        dramatically speed up Connection tests. (If no preferredTestQuery is set, the
        default ConnectionTester executes a getTables() call on the Connection's 
        DatabaseMetaData. Depending on your database, this may execute more slowly 
        than a "normal" database query.)
 ....
```

Comment: Amazing. This only change increased performance like 3 times.

Comment: And also it's even better if you increase mysql MAX_CONNECTIONS to 500 as well. I would mark this as answer, but suggestions from Steve Waldman below are also very useful.

Answer (score 1):

So there is a basic problem:

You have a pool which maxes out at 200 Connections. You have 500 concurrent clients. If database operations are much slower than anything else your app is doing (not uncommon, as it's network IO), for every two client Threads using a database Connection, there will be three wait()ing, e.g. in awaitAvailable(). If this is the core of your issue, it would be pool independent, and could only be solved by increasing maxPoolSize.

But there are c3p0-specific issues too. c3p0 is a "thicker" pool than most, especially thicker than the remarkably lightweight Hikari. There are (I hope) pluses to that in robustness and configurability, but potential performance costs. Here are some things you can do to improve performance of this application under c3p0:

1) Set [numHelperThreads](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#numHelperThreads) to a higher value than its default of 3, maybe to 10 or 20. c3p0 delegates many maintenance and testing tasks to a pool of helper threads. With the load you are throwing at it, with just 3 helper threads, these tasks are likely getting backed up, slowing down completion of check-ins of Connections and therefore availability to new clients.

2) Optimize your testing regime. As geert3 says, unless you are using the latest c3p0 [c3p0-0.9.5-pre10] and a JDBC4 compliant driver, you are falling back to a very slow test. You are also testing on checkout, which will slow down each client Thread. See [here](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#simple_advice_on_connection_testing) for some advice.

3) Set much larger [minPoolSize](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#minPoolSize) and/or [acquireIncrement](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#acquireIncrement). Your pool is starting at a tiny size, and growing by batches of just 3 Connections. It will take some time under these settings to get to your full maxPoolSize of 200 (which is still insufficient to cover your load without waits). During the transition period while the pool grows from small to large, your 500 clients will spend a LOT of time just wait()ing.